# linking codes and arrays between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i have a array "v" in sheet 3 and i need to copy the last column of it to sheet one using a loop.it is only working if i am on sheet 3. i want it to work regardless of what sheet i am on.  In this loop  i have

```
    For i = 1 To Cells(12, 8).Value  'this cell is in sheet 2


    'i need this Cells(7, i + 8).Value  output to be in sheet 1 
Cells(7, i + 8).Value = v(i, UBound(v, 1))

    Next i

   ' for the array 
    With Worksheets("three")
    Const firstCol As Long = 7, firstRow As Long = 12

        lastCol = Sheet3.Cells(firstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row


         v= Range(Cells(firstRow, firstCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
            End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

braX

This should get it done:

```
Dim Src as Worksheet
Dim Dst as Worksheet 

Set Dst = Worksheets("One") 'I assume this isn't the real name?
Set Src = Worksheets("Three") 'I assume this isn't the real name?

'You'll progablly want to dim/set this sheet also but I don't know what to call it
 For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 8).Value  'this cell is in sheet 2


    'i need this Cells(7, i + 8).Value  output to be in sheet 1 
   Dst.Cells(7, i + 8).Value = v(i, UBound(v, 1))

    Next i

   ' for the array 
    With Src
        Const firstCol As Long = 7, firstRow As Long = 12

        lastCol = .Cells(firstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row

'*** Don't know which sheet formula below is looking at but you get the gist
         v= Range(Cells(firstRow, firstCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    End With 'Src
```

HTH

Comment: okay i got your point but as for the array "v" it is not possible to write: Src.v- so that i can tell the system that it is from sheet 3. i tried that and it dd not work. My problem is how to tell the system that the array is in sheet 3.

Comment: okay worked now i added .Src to the cells in the last line of code and it worked out well thank you . it was a problem to me. thank you for your help.

Comment: Ali, Id you create a Dynamic Range Name for your array you can then access it using the name. A Dynamic Range Name will adjust as you add/delete rows to your array so you won't need code in your macro to figure it out every time it is run. Query: Excel Dynamic Range for more information.